# how to make jplayer play the same song after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jplayer

I am making jPlayer function on Ajax so that if page of my website refreshed, jPlayer should continue with it's current song and so on. I am able to store the information of tracks and current tracks on refresh but unable to run it on jPlayer though it is running from start.

Comment: Anyone.. anything...

Comment: Ok... Can anyone tell me that if I have index key, for ex. no. 4 song is playing and i got the key number 4 so how could i play the number 4 song after refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the index number to play the track.

eg. 
myPlaylist.play(parseInt(cur_track_data));

also add this to playlistOption
{
autoPlay:true
}